# Database migration plugin error in grails4

Tags: gradle, grails, groovy, database-migration

I am working on a grails project version 4

And whenever I am running the project or performing gradle build or clean

I am getting the following error

```
> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':classpath'.
   > Could not find org.grails.plugins:database-migration:3.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://repo.grails.org/grails/core/org/grails/plugins/database-migration/3.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml
       - https://repo.grails.org/grails/core/org/grails/plugins/database-migration/3.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/database-migration-3.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.pom
       - https://repo.grails.org/grails/core/org/grails/plugins/database-migration/3.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/database-migration-3.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar
     Required by:
         project :
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Seems like all of the plugin repos return 404 right now, examples:

- https://repo.grails.org/grails/core/org/grails/plugins/database-migration/3.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/database-migration-3.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.pom
- https://repo.grails.org/grails/core/gradle/plugin/com/gorylenko/gradle-git-properties/gradle-git-properties/2.2.4/gradle-git-properties-2.2.4.pom

not sure whats going on, but if you are using grails 3+ you can try to add `https://grails.jfrog.io/grails/core` to your repositories closure (as a temporary fix), like so:

```
repositories {
  mavenLocal()
  maven { url "https://repo.grails.org/grails/core" }
  maven { url "https://grails.jfrog.io/grails/core"}
}
```

Although I would like to know whats going on with the official repo, maybe hear from the grails guys about this.
I hope they resolve it soon at least, because its not as easy to fix with our old grails 2 apps.

Comment: Added the url in repositories closure did not work
i am using grails version 4

Comment: I have `repositories` twice, once in buildscript and one further down, without another wrapper around it. where did you add it? buildscript alone doesnt work

Comment: Because the pom file exists in the jfrog repo: 

https://grails.jfrog.io/grails/core/org/grails/plugins/database-migration/3.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/database-migration-3.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.pom

Comment: Seems like it's fixed now at least for Grails 3+ https://github.com/grails/grails-core/issues/11825

Answer (score 0):

```
https://grails.jfrog.io/grails/core
```

Works for me by using grails 4! Thanks!
I hope the repo.grails.org-guys will fix this problem as soon.

Answer (score 0):

They fixed the problem teporary on "https://repo.grails.org/grails/core".

The link will forwart on "https://repo.grails.org/artifactory/core/" which has all repositories.

Good luck!